# Excel VBA select multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select multiple columns, i.e. Column `A` to Column `F` and Column `H` using the following formula:

```
enodebdata.Range(enodebdata.Range("A2:F2, H2"), enodebdata.Range("A2:F2, H2").End(xlDown).Range("F2")).Select
```

The problem is it only selects Columns `A` to `F` and gives the following error:

> Runtime error 424, Object required`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing the range string to `"A2:F2, H2:H2"`

Comment: You may also want ot take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @braX it still only selects column `A` to `F`. This is how I've modified it: `enodebdata.Range(enodebdata.Range("A2:F2, H2:H2"), enodebdata.Range("A2:F2, H2:H2").End(xlDown).Range("F2")).Select`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for the link. Good to know

Comment: That `.Range("F2")` doesn't look right. Why not find the last row and specify the range that way?

Comment: @SJR I don't think I understand what you mean? How do you mean?

Comment: See GMalc's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Union`.

```
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = enodebdata.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Union(enodebdata.Range("A2:F" & lrow), enodebdata.Range("H2:H" & lrow)).Select
```